Fade In/Out objects in a complex scene
I'm making an isometric apartment renovation video. It's a few minutes long and a continuous shot. Lots of objects need to appear and disappear with fades In/Out. Rendering with Cycles.
As far as I know there is 2 ways to do the fading and both ways bring serious downsides.
1 - Animate the Alpha value on all the materials of the objects that need to fade. A bit tedious but doable with drivers (or do it using an attribute). But the fading looks wrong because you see the backfaces, and obliques faces are less transparent. It breaks the illusion in my opinion and look cheap unless the fading is very fast.

2 - View layers. This actually looks good but working with them on a scene like this is annoying. It's difficult to deal with all the keyframes and keep a global view of the scene. What you see in the viewport is not what you get so you have to keep rendering, and the rendering time is multiplied by the number of layers. You can manage with only one extra View Layer that you turn on and off just for fading objects and animate an Alpha Over node in compositing but this is difficult to manage and iterate upon. Good luck retiming your animations though when you need to offset hundreds of keyframes across objects data, view layers, and compositor.

So my question is can the proper fading be achieved in shader somehow? And if not, is there another way? And if not, any tips on working with view layers to make it easier?
